# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

I have a Java method that returns a `Dataset<Row>`. I want to convert this to a `Dataset<Object>`, where the Object is named StatusChangeDB. I have created a POJO StatusChangeDB.java and coded it with all the query objects found in the mySQL table.
I then create a Encoder and convert the `Dataset<Row>` to a `Dataset<StatusChangeDB>`. However when I try to .show() the values of the `Dataset<StatusChangeDB>` I receive the error

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`hvpinid_quad`' given input columns:
> ```
>
> [status_change_type, superLayer, loclayer, sector, locwire];
>
> ```
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:86)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:83)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:290)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:290)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:289)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:287)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:287)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:287)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:287)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:287)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(TreeNode.scala:324)
>
> at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>
> at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>
> at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>
> at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>
> at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>
> at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:311)
>
> at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>
> at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:25)
>
> at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$class.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:88)
>
> at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:311)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:287)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:255)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:255)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:266)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:276)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$6.apply(QueryPlan.scala:285)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:285)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:255)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:83)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:76)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:128)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:76)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:57)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:259)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:209)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:167)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:58)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:376)
> ```

I do not know how to have whomever replicate this, but here are some methods that are used on my end. I hope the error can be seen from the following codes:

```
public static Dataset<Row> mySqlDataset() {
    SparkSession spSession = getSession();
    spSession.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false");
    Dataset<Row> demoDf = spSession.read().format("jdbc").options(jdbcOptions()).load();

    return demoDf;
}
```

where jdbcOptions() are

```
public static Map<String, String> jdbcOptions() {
        Map<String, String> jdbcOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jdbcOptions.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        jdbcOptions.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        jdbcOptions.put("dbtable", "status_change");
        jdbcOptions.put("user", "root");
        jdbcOptions.put("password", "");

        return jdbcOptions;
    }
```

the method that fails is

```
public Dataset<StatusChangeDB> compareRunII(String str) {
    Dataset<Row> tempDF = SparkManager.mySqlDataset()
            .select("loclayer", "superLayer", "sector", "locwire", "status_change_type")
            .filter(col("runno").equalTo(str));
    return tempDF.as(SparkManager.statusChangeDBEncoder());

}
```

where SparkManager.statusChangeDBEncoder() is

```
public static Encoder<StatusChangeDB> statusChangeDBEncoder() {
    return Encoders.bean(StatusChangeDB.class);
}
```

and StatusChangeDB is just a POJO that works because I am able to create `Dataset<StatusChangeDB>` from a datafile, but this doesnt work for a sql query. Why?

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.CompareToBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class StatusChangeDB implements Comparable<StatusChangeDB> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int statchangeid;
    private Timestamp dateofentry;
    private int runno;
    private String status_change_type;
    private String problem_type;
    private String region;
    private String sector;
    private String superlayer;
    private String loclayer;
    private String locwire;
    private String hvcrateid;
    private String hvslotid;
    private String hvchannelid;
    private String hvpinid_region;
    private String hvpinid_quad;
    private String hvpinid_doublet;
    private String hvpinid_doublethalf;

    private String hvpinid_pin;
    private String dcrbconnectorid_slot;
    private String dcrbconnectorid_connector;
    private String lvfuseid_row;
    private String lvfuseid_col;

    public StatusChangeDB() {
    }

    public int getStatchangeid() {
        return statchangeid;
    }

    public void setStatchangeid(int statchangeid) {
        this.statchangeid = statchangeid;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateofentry() {
        return dateofentry;
    }

    public void setDateofentry(Timestamp dateofentry) {
        this.dateofentry = dateofentry;
    }

    public int getRunno() {
        return runno;
    }

    public void setRunno(int runno) {
        this.runno = runno;
    }

    public String getStatus_change_type() {
        return status_change_type;
    }

    public void setStatus_change_type(String status_change_type) {
        this.status_change_type = status_change_type;
    }

    public String getProblem_type() {
        return problem_type;
    }

    public void setProblem_type(String problem_type) {
        this.problem_type = problem_type;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public String getSector() {
        return sector;
    }

    public void setSector(String sector) {
        this.sector = sector;
    }

    public String getSuperlayer() {
        return superlayer;
    }

    public void setSuperlayer(String superlayer) {
        this.superlayer = superlayer;
    }

    public String getLoclayer() {
        return loclayer;
    }

    public void setLoclayer(String loclayer) {
        this.loclayer = loclayer;
    }

    public String getLocwire() {
        return locwire;
    }

    public void setLocwire(String locwire) {
        this.locwire = locwire;
    }

    public String getHvcrateid() {
        return hvcrateid;
    }

    public void setHvcrateid(String hvcrateid) {
        this.hvcrateid = hvcrateid;
    }

    public String getHvslotid() {
        return hvslotid;
    }

    public void setHvslotid(String hvslotid) {
        this.hvslotid = hvslotid;
    }

    public String getHvchannelid() {
        return hvchannelid;
    }

    public void setHvchannelid(String hvchannelid) {
        this.hvchannelid = hvchannelid;
    }

    public String getHvpinid_region() {
        return hvpinid_region;
    }

    public void setHvpinid_region(String hvpinid_region) {
        this.hvpinid_region = hvpinid_region;
    }

    public String getHvpinid_quad() {
        return hvpinid_quad;
    }

    public void setHvpinid_quad(String hvpinid_quad) {
        this.hvpinid_quad = hvpinid_quad;
    }

    public String getHvpinid_doublet() {
        return hvpinid_doublet;
    }

    public void setHvpinid_doublet(String hvpinid_doublet) {
        this.hvpinid_doublet = hvpinid_doublet;
    }

    public String getHvpinid_doublethalf() {
        return hvpinid_doublethalf;
    }

    public void setHvpinid_doublethalf(String hvpinid_doublethalf) {
        this.hvpinid_doublethalf = hvpinid_doublethalf;
    }

    public String getHvpinid_pin() {
        return hvpinid_pin;
    }

    public void setHvpinid_pin(String hvpinid_pin) {
        this.hvpinid_pin = hvpinid_pin;
    }

    public String getDcrbconnectorid_slot() {
        return dcrbconnectorid_slot;
    }

    public void setDcrbconnectorid_slot(String dcrbconnectorid_slot) {
        this.dcrbconnectorid_slot = dcrbconnectorid_slot;
    }

    public String getDcrbconnectorid_connector() {
        return dcrbconnectorid_connector;
    }

    public void setDcrbconnectorid_connector(String dcrbconnectorid_connector) {
        this.dcrbconnectorid_connector = dcrbconnectorid_connector;
    }

    public String getLvfuseid_row() {
        return lvfuseid_row;
    }

    public void setLvfuseid_row(String lvfuseid_row) {
        this.lvfuseid_row = lvfuseid_row;
    }

    public String getLvfuseid_col() {
        return lvfuseid_col;
    }

    public void setLvfuseid_col(String lvfuseid_col) {
        this.lvfuseid_col = lvfuseid_col;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ToStringBuilder builder = new ToStringBuilder(this);
        builder.append("statchangeid", statchangeid);
        builder.append("dateofentry", dateofentry);
        builder.append("runno", runno);
        builder.append("status_change_type", status_change_type);
        builder.append("problem_type", problem_type);
        builder.append("region", region);
        builder.append("sector", sector);
        builder.append("superlayer", superlayer);
        builder.append("loclayer", loclayer);
        builder.append("locwire", locwire);
        builder.append("hvcrateid", hvcrateid);
        builder.append("hvslotid", hvslotid);
        builder.append("hvchannelid", hvchannelid);
        builder.append("hvpinid_region", hvpinid_region);
        builder.append("hvpinid_quad", hvpinid_quad);
        builder.append("hvpinid_doublet", hvpinid_doublet);
        builder.append("hvpinid_doublethalf", hvpinid_doublethalf);
        builder.append("hvpinid_pin", hvpinid_pin);
        builder.append("dcrbconnectorid_slot", dcrbconnectorid_slot);
        builder.append("dcrbconnectorid_connector", dcrbconnectorid_connector);
        builder.append("lvfuseid_row", lvfuseid_row);
        builder.append("lvfuseid_col", lvfuseid_col);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final StatusChangeDB other) {
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(statchangeid, other.statchangeid).append(dateofentry, other.dateofentry)
                .append(runno, other.runno).append(status_change_type, other.status_change_type)
                .append(problem_type, other.problem_type).append(region, other.region).append(sector, other.sector)
                .append(superlayer, other.superlayer).append(loclayer, other.loclayer).append(locwire, other.locwire)
                .append(hvcrateid, other.hvcrateid).append(hvslotid, other.hvslotid)
                .append(hvchannelid, other.hvchannelid).append(hvpinid_region, other.hvpinid_region)
                .append(hvpinid_quad, other.hvpinid_quad).append(hvpinid_doublet, other.hvpinid_doublet)
                .append(hvpinid_doublethalf, other.hvpinid_doublethalf).append(hvpinid_pin, other.hvpinid_pin)
                .append(dcrbconnectorid_slot, other.dcrbconnectorid_slot)
                .append(dcrbconnectorid_connector, other.dcrbconnectorid_connector)
                .append(lvfuseid_row, other.lvfuseid_row).append(lvfuseid_col, other.lvfuseid_col).toComparison();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dateofentry == null) ? 0 : dateofentry.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dcrbconnectorid_connector == null) ? 0 : dcrbconnectorid_connector.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dcrbconnectorid_slot == null) ? 0 : dcrbconnectorid_slot.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvchannelid == null) ? 0 : hvchannelid.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvcrateid == null) ? 0 : hvcrateid.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvpinid_doublet == null) ? 0 : hvpinid_doublet.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvpinid_doublethalf == null) ? 0 : hvpinid_doublethalf.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvpinid_pin == null) ? 0 : hvpinid_pin.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvpinid_quad == null) ? 0 : hvpinid_quad.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvpinid_region == null) ? 0 : hvpinid_region.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((hvslotid == null) ? 0 : hvslotid.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((loclayer == null) ? 0 : loclayer.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((locwire == null) ? 0 : locwire.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lvfuseid_col == null) ? 0 : lvfuseid_col.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lvfuseid_row == null) ? 0 : lvfuseid_row.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((problem_type == null) ? 0 : problem_type.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((region == null) ? 0 : region.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + runno;
        result = prime * result + ((sector == null) ? 0 : sector.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + statchangeid;
        result = prime * result + ((status_change_type == null) ? 0 : status_change_type.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((superlayer == null) ? 0 : superlayer.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        StatusChangeDB other = (StatusChangeDB) obj;
        if (dateofentry == null) {
            if (other.dateofentry != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dateofentry.equals(other.dateofentry))
            return false;
        if (dcrbconnectorid_connector == null) {
            if (other.dcrbconnectorid_connector != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dcrbconnectorid_connector.equals(other.dcrbconnectorid_connector))
            return false;
        if (dcrbconnectorid_slot == null) {
            if (other.dcrbconnectorid_slot != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dcrbconnectorid_slot.equals(other.dcrbconnectorid_slot))
            return false;
        if (hvchannelid == null) {
            if (other.hvchannelid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvchannelid.equals(other.hvchannelid))
            return false;
        if (hvcrateid == null) {
            if (other.hvcrateid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvcrateid.equals(other.hvcrateid))
            return false;
        if (hvpinid_doublet == null) {
            if (other.hvpinid_doublet != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvpinid_doublet.equals(other.hvpinid_doublet))
            return false;
        if (hvpinid_doublethalf == null) {
            if (other.hvpinid_doublethalf != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvpinid_doublethalf.equals(other.hvpinid_doublethalf))
            return false;
        if (hvpinid_pin == null) {
            if (other.hvpinid_pin != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvpinid_pin.equals(other.hvpinid_pin))
            return false;
        if (hvpinid_quad == null) {
            if (other.hvpinid_quad != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvpinid_quad.equals(other.hvpinid_quad))
            return false;
        if (hvpinid_region == null) {
            if (other.hvpinid_region != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvpinid_region.equals(other.hvpinid_region))
            return false;
        if (hvslotid == null) {
            if (other.hvslotid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!hvslotid.equals(other.hvslotid))
            return false;
        if (loclayer == null) {
            if (other.loclayer != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!loclayer.equals(other.loclayer))
            return false;
        if (locwire == null) {
            if (other.locwire != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!locwire.equals(other.locwire))
            return false;
        if (lvfuseid_col == null) {
            if (other.lvfuseid_col != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lvfuseid_col.equals(other.lvfuseid_col))
            return false;
        if (lvfuseid_row == null) {
            if (other.lvfuseid_row != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lvfuseid_row.equals(other.lvfuseid_row))
            return false;
        if (problem_type == null) {
            if (other.problem_type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!problem_type.equals(other.problem_type))
            return false;
        if (region == null) {
            if (other.region != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!region.equals(other.region))
            return false;
        if (runno != other.runno)
            return false;
        if (sector == null) {
            if (other.sector != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sector.equals(other.sector))
            return false;
        if (statchangeid != other.statchangeid)
            return false;
        if (status_change_type == null) {
            if (other.status_change_type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!status_change_type.equals(other.status_change_type))
            return false;
        if (superlayer == null) {
            if (other.superlayer != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!superlayer.equals(other.superlayer))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

There is no help on Google or this forum for this error.

Comment: What argument are you putting into `compareRunIT`? Is it `hvpinid_quad`?

Comment: No, it was a dumb overlook that converting a dataset that does not have the necessary values. In my attempt, I first filtered than tried to convert. It should be convert, then filter.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of headbanging the simple answer was changing

```
public Dataset<StatusChangeDB> compareRunII(String str) {
     Dataset<Row> tempDF = SparkManager.mySqlDataset()
     .select("loclayer", "superLayer", "sector", "locwire",
     "status_change_type")
     .filter(col("runno").equalTo(str));
    return tempDF.as(SparkManager.statusChangeDBEncoder());

}
```

to

```
public Dataset<StatusChangeDB> compareRunII(String str) {
    Dataset<Row> tempDF = SparkManager.mySqlDataset().filter(col("runno").equalTo(str));
    return tempDF.as(SparkManager.statusChangeDBEncoder());

}
```